# Primefaces: selectOneMenu, al momento de verlo en la web no me muestra los items añadidos al componente

Tags: bootstrap, eclipse, primefaces, java-ee

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion Java Web utilizando el framework Primefaces, en lo que es css con bootstrap (Plantilla AdminLTE), el inconveniente que tengo es que cuando programa un componente de primefaces en este caso un p:selectOneMenu, al momento de verlo en la web no me muestra los items añadidos al componente.

Codigo:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="../WEB-INF/templates/menu_admin.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="header">

    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">

        <p:selectOneMenu style="width:180px;height:28px;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;"
                                                 effect="fade"
                                                 filter="false"
                                                 filterMatchMode="contains">
                                    <f:selectItem   itemLabel="[Seleccione]"
                                                    itemValue="0"
                                                    itemDisabled="false"
                                                    noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                    <f:selectItem   itemValue="M"
                                                    itemLabel="Masculino"/>
                                    <f:selectItem   itemValue="F"
                                                    itemLabel="Femenino"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Algunas veces este problema se debe a que Primefaces "incorpora o se basa" en Jquery; entonces, pueda ser que el css de bootstrap que estabas utilizando también incorpore Jquery. De ahí el conflicto que se te generó.

Answer (score 0):

El primer consejo que te daría es no mezclar tantas tecnologías de parte del FRONT, con primefaces es mas que suficiente. Por otra parte basta con solo poner esto en tu etiqueta de plantillas:

```
<html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
<ui:composition  template="/WEB-INF/templates/menu_admin.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">

<p:selectOneMenu style="width:180px;height:28px;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;"
                                             effect="fade"
                                             filter="false"
                                             filterMatchMode="contains">
                                <f:selectItem   itemLabel="[Seleccione]"
                                                itemValue="0"
                                                itemDisabled="false"
                                                noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItem   itemValue="M"
                                                itemLabel="Masculino"/>
                                <f:selectItem   itemValue="F"
                                                itemLabel="Femenino"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>


</ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque falta el valor que quieres setear asi como tienes propiedades como effect="fade" esta la propiedad value la cual quedaría algo así.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBean.miVariableString}"
                 style="width:180px;height:28px;font-size:12px;font:family:Arial;" 
                 effect="fade" filter="false" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="[Seleccione]" itemValue="0" itemDisabled="false" noSelectionOption="true"/>
     <f:selectItem   itemValue="M" itemLabel="Masculino"/>
     <f:selectItem   itemValue="F" itemLabel="Femenino"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Por otra parte si tienes el filter="false" no es necesario que tengas el filterMatchMode="contains" lo puedes quitar ahora si quieres que tenga el filtro lo cambias a true.

Saludos, espero haber ayudado.